# ARCore 2D object not properly sticking to anchor

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, opengl-es, arcore

I've been tinkering with the [HelloAR Xamarin sample](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/Android/ARCore). Currently, I'm working with some 2D shapes and I'm trying to tie a triangle to an anchor. It *mostly works*, when turning my phone on place the triangle seems to stick to its anchor and while moving back and forth the triangle shrinks and grows. However, while moving the phone (ie: moving myself sideways parallel to the face of the triangle), the triangle slightly moves in the same direction as the camera. Similarly, while moving back and forth, the triangle does move up and down in the scene. Here are some pictures that show what's happening (vertical lines added by me):

[image]

As you can see from the pictures, as I move to the left, the triangle is slowly creeping up to the side of the laptop while also slowly disappearing from the frame. I feel like my code is pretty similar to the [ObjectRenderer.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/blob/master/Android/ARCore/samples/HelloAR/Rendering/ObjectRenderer.cs) used in the original sample. Here are my equivalents of `updateModelMatrix`, `CreateOnGlThread` and `Draw`:

```
public void updateModelMatrix(float[] modelMatrix, float scaleFactor) {
        float[] scaleMatrix = new float[16];
        Android.Opengl.Matrix.SetIdentityM(scaleMatrix, 0);
        scaleMatrix[0] = scaleFactor;
        scaleMatrix[5] = scaleFactor;
        scaleMatrix[10] = scaleFactor;
        Android.Opengl.Matrix.MultiplyMM(mViewMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0, scaleMatrix, 0);
    }

public void CreateOnGlThread(Context _context) {
        vertexBuffer = ByteBuffer
                    .AllocateDirect(triangleCords.Length * BYTES_PER_FLOAT).Order(ByteOrder.NativeOrder())
                    .AsFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.Put(triangleCords).Position(0);

        indices = ByteBuffer.AllocateDirect(BYTES_PER_SHORT * triangleIndices.Length)
            .Order(ByteOrder.NativeOrder()).AsShortBuffer();
        indices.Put(triangleIndices).Position(0);

        int[] buffers = new int[2];
        GLES20.GlGenBuffers(2, buffers, 0);
        mVertexBufferId = buffers[0];
        mIndexBufferId = buffers[1];

        GLES20.GlBindBuffer(GLES20.GlArrayBuffer, mVertexBufferId);
        GLES20.GlBufferData(GLES20.GlArrayBuffer, triangleCords.Length * BYTES_PER_FLOAT, vertexBuffer, GLES20.GlStaticDraw);
        GLES20.GlBindBuffer(GLES20.GlArrayBuffer, mVertexBufferId);

        GLES20.GlBindBuffer(GLES20.GlElementArrayBuffer, mIndexBufferId);
        mIndexCount = triangleIndices.Length;
        GLES20.GlBufferData(
            GLES20.GlElementArrayBuffer, BYTES_PER_SHORT * mIndexCount, indices, GLES20.GlStaticDraw);
        GLES20.GlBindBuffer(GLES20.GlElementArrayBuffer, mIndexBufferId);

        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GlVertexShader, vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GlFragmentShader, fragmentShaderCode);

        program = GLES20.GlCreateProgram();
        GLES20.GlAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        GLES20.GlAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
        GLES20.GlLinkProgram(program);
        positionHandle = GLES20.GlGetAttribLocation(program, "a_Position");
        colorHandle = GLES20.GlGetUniformLocation(program, "vColor");
        mModerViewMatrixHandle = GLES20.GlGetUniformLocation(program, "u_ModelView");
        mModelViewProjectionMatrixHandle = GLES20.GlGetUniformLocation(program, "u_ModelViewProjection");
        Android.Opengl.Matrix.SetIdentityM(mViewMatrix, 0);
    }
public void Draw(float[] _cameraView, float[] _cameraPerspective) {
        Android.Opengl.Matrix.MultiplyMM(mModelViewMatrix, 0, _cameraView, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
        Android.Opengl.Matrix.MultiplyMM(mModelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, _cameraPerspective, 0, mModelViewMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.GlUseProgram(program);
        GLES20.GlBindBuffer(GLES20.GlArrayBuffer, mVertexBufferId);

        GLES20.GlVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GlFloat, false, 0, 0);
        GLES20.GlEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);

        GLES20.GlUniform4fv(colorHandle, 1, COLOR, 0);
        GLES20.GlUniformMatrix4fv(mModerViewMatrixHandle, 1, false, mModelViewMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.GlUniformMatrix4fv(mModelViewProjectionMatrixHandle, 1, false, mModelViewProjectionMatrix, 0);


        GLES20.GlBindBuffer(GLES20.GlElementArrayBuffer, mIndexBufferId);
        GLES20.GlDrawElements(GLES20.GlTriangles, mIndexCount, GLES20.GlUnsignedShort, 0);
        GLES20.GlBindBuffer(GLES20.GlArrayBuffer, 0);
        GLES20.GlBindBuffer(GLES20.GlElementArrayBuffer, 0);
    }
```

The parameters passed onto these functions coming from the `GLSurfaceView.IRenderer.OnDrawFrame` shouldn't be different from those from the original sample:

```
void GLSurfaceView.IRenderer.OnDrawFrame(IGL10 gl)
    {
        ...

        try {
            Frame frame = session.Update();
            Camera camera = frame.Camera;
            ...

            if (tap != null && camera.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking) {
                foreach (var hit in frame.HitTest(tap)) {

                    var trackable = hit.Trackable;
                    if (trackable is Plane && ((Plane)trackable).IsPoseInPolygon(hit.HitPose)) {

                        shapeAnchor = hit.CreateAnchor();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            backgroundRenderer.Draw(frame);

            if (shapeAnchor != null && shapeAnchor.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking) {
                float[] projmtx = new float[16];
                camera.GetProjectionMatrix(projmtx, 0, 0.1f, 100.0f);

                float[] viewmtx = new float[16];
                camera.GetViewMatrix(viewmtx, 0);

                shapeAnchor.Pose.ToMatrix(anchorMatrix, 0);
                triangleRenderer.updateModelMatrix(anchorMatrix, 1);
                triangleRenderer.Draw(viewmtx, projmtx);
            }


        } catch (Exception _ex) {
            var x = true;
        }
    }
```

Also, my vertex shader is fairly simple:

```
        private string vertexShaderCode =
        "uniform mat4 u_ModelView;" +
        "uniform mat4 u_ModelViewProjection;" +
        "attribute vec4 a_Position;" +
        "varying vec3 v_ViewPosition;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  v_ViewPosition = (u_ModelView * a_Position).xyz;" +
        "  gl_Position = u_ModelViewProjection * a_Position;" +
        "}";
```

The fact that eventually it does goes out of frame is a bit puzzling to me, there's definitely something wrong with how I'm using the matrices when moving to 2D objects. Any ideas?